# Do I need to enable Network Discovery to install a printer connected to a home router?

Tags: networking, router, printer, home-networking, network-printer

#### Scenario

I'm considering purchasing a home network printer but first wanted to verify the prerequisites for configuring the PCs & laptops that are connected to my home network, so that all devices can print to the new printer.

Let's say I have the following setup:

- I have a printer connected directly to my home router with a wired ethernet connection.
- I have several PCs & laptops running a mixture of Windows 7 & 10 connecting to my home router via a mixture of wired & wireless connections.
- Network discovery is turned **off** by default on all PCs & laptops, with the network location set to the default `Public Network`.

#### Goal

I wish to be able to print to the network printer from all PCs & laptops connected to the home router either wired or wirelessly.

#### Anticipated Steps

From my own experience & research, I anticipate the setup to be as follows:

- Connect printer to home router via wired ethernet connection.
- Print Network Configuration page to obtain printer IP address.
- Log onto home router and reserve printer IP address.
- On each PC or laptop:

  - Open Control Panel
  - Devices & Printers
  - Add Printer
  - Add Network Printer
  - Add Printer by TCP/IP Address
  - Enter reserved printer IP address
  - Query printer for appropriate driver

However, I'm unsure whether or not I need to enable **Network Discovery** for the above to be successful, and if so, I'm unsure of the implications for doing so?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you connect the printer directly to the network it shouldn't be required.  However, if you connect the printer to a PC, then share the printer then it might be required.  However, network discovery within your own intranet, is perfectly safe.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ramhound - I'd hoped that would be the case. The main reason for my uncertainty was that, as a test, I thought I'd try to ping one of the PCs/laptops on the network from another PC/laptop, and the ping failed. Hence I wondered whether, if I were to connect the printer, that the PCs/laptops would be similarly unable to communicate with the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to enable Network discovery to add a printer. Your anticipated steps are correct because you know the IP of the printer. If you did not know the IP and needed to search the network for a printer, then you would need to turn it on to find the device.

Comment: I am not even sure network discovery would have to be enabled to find a network printer.  It’s been awhile since I worried about network discovery being enabled though.